# Pg_connect or die() not returning anything

Tags: php, psql

I have the following code to connect to psql. "test1" is the only thing that displays on the page, meaning that something goes wrong in the pg_connect, but the "Could not connect" message doesn't display either. What could be going wrong here? I'm using the same credentials that allow me to connect via navicat.

```
<?php

echo 'test1';

$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5439 dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypass") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

echo 'test2';

?>
```

Comment: Try changing connect line to `... or die('Could not connect');` and see if there is any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't have PostreSQL extension enabled.

Make sure you in your php.ini file you have line:

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

without ; at the beginning.

If you have ; at the beginning remove ; and restart server

You may also at the beginning of your file add:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to make sure what the problem is